# jQuery <li>s sum width problem

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a submenu which looks like:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="mainMenu clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Eurodan huset</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hustyper</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10 byggesten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Huse til salg</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Udstillinger</a>
        <ul class="underMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Salgskontorer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Velkommen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Historie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fremtidens boliger</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Grunde</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Katalog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where `.mainMenu` is the big menu and `.underMenu` is a list with "underpages" from main menu. To make the under menu works I need a fixed width for it (it has position absolute and the `<li>` parent has `position:relative` so I make it using jquery.

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
$('.underMenu').each(function() {
    var t = $(this),
        tW = 0;

    $('li', t).each(function() {
        tW += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    t.css('width', tW);

});
```

Following code above, my under menu should looks ok (the way I think) but the problem is that it looks like this:

[image]

To make it to work I need to add 40px more to the width of `.underMenu`, but I can't understand where the problem is since I use `$(this).outerWidth(true);`.

According to my thinking everything should work ok but as you can see, it doesn't.

**CSS:**

```
.mainMenu,
.underMenu {
    clear:both;
    line-height:29px;
    background:url(../images/transPxBlack.png) repeat left top;
    -moz-border-radius:16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius:16px;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.mainMenu > li {
    margin-left:16px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:13px;
}
.mainMenu > li:first-child {margin-left:0;}

.underMenu {position:absolute;}
.underMenu li {
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left:18px;
}
.underMenu li:first-child {margin-left:0;}
```

Comment: how about creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we have something to work with?

Comment: Yes, of course : http://jsfiddle.net/CTYNG/

Comment: Does `outerWidth` handle `border-radius`? I'd disable those in the css and see if it fixes things up.

Comment: @steaveax `.outerWidth()` does indeed handle the border; [Description: Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

Comment: @steveax : Border-radius is on ".underMenu" and "outerWidth" on its childrens, "<li>s" so doesn't metter. I removed border-radius from parent but it sill doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your width calculation is working at the sum of the width of the child `li` tags, but it isn't accounting for the padding on the `.underMenu` so your overall width comes up short.  If you add the padding in, it works:

```
$('.underMenu').each(function(){
    var t = $(this),
        tW = 0;

    $('li', t).each(function(){
        tW += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    t.css('width', tW + t.outerWidth(true) - t.width());
});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CTuz3/

Comment: Thanx, i got the idea about the problem. I modified the code a bit thinking that the css will be modified in time (maybe not, but nevermind), so my tW is declared in this way tW = parseInt(t.css('padding-left')) + parseInt(t.css('padding-right'));

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is workiong fine. Add `display:inline-block` and `float:left` to `.underMenu li` rule you will see as expected.

```
            .underMenu li {
                font-size:11px;
                margin-left:18px;
                display:inline-block;
                float:left;
            }
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5NMM/1/)**

Comment: I added display:inline-block; but it still doesn't work. Also i opened your example and it's wrong. I added a float:left; ".mainMenu > li" to arrange items (you modified my mark-up a bit) but the under menu still doesn't work. What I can notice is that if i put tW += $(this).outerWidth(true) + 10; works, but i want to understand where te problem is.

Comment: I did not modify your markup just modified the css. The fiddle works fine.